# Edit google sheets cell with a GET URL

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to edit cell A1 with a hyperlink. For example

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value="change](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value=%22change) the value of this cell"

If not is there a way to access GET URL information in google app scripts to pass parameters. The answer might simply be no for the year 2020.

Example

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value="1"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value=%221%22)

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value="2"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet/edit#gid=sheet&range=a1&value=%222%22)

If you click the first link it changes the value of A1 to 1 and if you click the second link it changes the value of A1 to 2.

Comment: Please add more details as well a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Suggestion start looking at https://developers.google.com/sheets

Comment: @Rubén I think this is more of a yes or no question. I can use the URL to go to a specific range, but can you embed in the URL a command to edit a particular cell.

Comment: AFAIK Yes/No questions are not a good fit for SE sites.Anyway, you should use the Sheets API or use Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Rubén I added a little bit more since your link made me think of something else. Basically what I am trying to figure out is if we can pass parameters into the GET URL that can be accessed by google app scripts or if there is already a built in parameter to change the cell value, does that make sense? I know of many other ways to resolve this particular problem but just wanted to know if it was possible with a plain URL.

Comment: (I edited my previous comment, anyway) If you want to use the Sheets API, the quesiton is off-topic here, if you want to use Google Apps Script, you might create a web app --> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Related [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/1595451)

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453492/3525368